# How to add content to a containerNode that already has its content from href using dijit.Dialog

Tags: javascript, xhtml, dialog, href, dojo

I’m new with this javascript and dijit.

My problem: In my js-function I’m building up a dijit.Dialog, using parameters that has been sent to the function. 
One of the parameters is a href to en external xhtml-file that contains only the text that’s supposed to be shown in the dialog. Now, I want to add a div with one more link to the dialog, in the containerNode (with a link that's supposed to be specific for every single user). 
The problem is that I can se that the added div is there until I reach dialog.show, after that it disapears. The text from the xhtml takes over. If I put it in the domNode (like the button) it shows up in the wrong place.
I've also tried another approach, to let the link be in the external href (in file three), give it an id and tried to reach it that way and manipulate it. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("bytlosen").href="www.xxx.se";
```

But it doesn't work. I get "document.getElementById(...) is null.

I would be SO happy if anyone can help me how to add the div (link) to the dialog! It doesn't matter if I

1. have it in file three and can reach it from file two and manipulate it,
2. simply adds the div in the js (in file two), or
3. any other way?

I have three files:

file one.xhtml (calling file two):

```
    <li><a href="#" onclick="new Xxxx.contactsDialog(Xxxx.CONTACT_INFO_TITLE, '${request.contextPath}/content/three.xhtml')">Kontakta oss</a></li>
```

file two.js:

```
    Xxxx.contactsDialog = function(title, href, cssClass, destroy) {
if (href) {
    var options = {
            title: title,
            href: href
    };
    if (cssClass)
        options["class"] = cssClass;                

    var dialog = new dijit.Dialog(options);             
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var bytLosen = document.createElement("a");
    bytLosen.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Byt lösenord"));
    bytLosen.setAttribute("href", "https://xxxx.xxx.se/xxx/xxx/xxxx=xxxx&TARGET=xxx.xxx.se");
    bytLosen.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    div.appendChild(bytLosen);
    dialog.containerNode.appendChild(div);

    var okButton = document.createElement("button");
    okButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    okButton.setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 10px");
    okButton.innerHTML = "Ok";
    dojo.addClass(okButton, "button");
    dialog.domNode.appendChild(okButton);

    dialog.startup();
    dialog.show();

    dojo.connect(okButton, "onclick", function() {
        dialog.hide();
        if (destroy) {
            dialog.destroy();
        }
    });
    return true;
} else
    return false;   
    };
```

file three.html:

```
    <div class="popupHeader">Synpunkter och felanmälan <span style="font-weight: normal">skickas till:</span></div>
    <div><a href="mailto:xxxxxx@xx.se">ajourhallning-xxx@xx.se</a></div>

    <div class="popupHeader">Länkar <span style="font-weight: normal">(till xxxx's externa hemsida)</span></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.se" target="_blank">www.xxxxx.se</a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.xxxxx.se/xxxxx" target="_blank">www.xxxx.se/xxx</a></div>

    <div class="popupHeader">Byt lösenord</div>
```

Comment: try it this way: `dialog.set('content', [div, okButton]);`

Comment: It still doesn't work the way I want it to. With your suggestion I get the link and the button, but I want the text from the xhtml-file also, but it doesn't show. Thanks anyway!

Comment: this could be done using AJAX, i guess... not the nicest solution but anyway: `var client = new XMLHttpRequest(); client.open('GET', '/one.xhtml'); client.onreadystatechange = function() { var c_div = document.createElement('div'); c_div.innerHTML = client.responseText; dialog.set('content', [div, okButton, c_div]); } client.send();`

Comment: Thank you so very very much, I got it to work with your last suggestion! Great!